# Trapping argument not working on SIGTSTP in bash script

Tags: bash, signals

Trapping argument not working on **SIGTSTP** in bash script.
When the ***Ctrl + C*** shortcut generates the **INT** signal, the "`echo Ctrl + C detected!`" command that I gave as an argument to the `trap` command runs. But the same situation does not work for the ***Ctrl + Z*** shortcut, ie **TSTP** signal. When I apply this shortcut the console does not print `echo Ctrl + C detected!` and it gets stuck. Please take a look at the script below and the output it produces to grasp the situation I am talking about.

**script.sh ;**

```
trap "echo Ctrl + Z detected !" SIGTSTP
trap "echo Ctrl + C detected !" SIGINT
sleep 101
```

**output;**

```
:~$ bash script.sh 
^CCtrl + C detected !
~$ bash script.sh 
^Z^Z^C
^C^C
^Z
```

Comment: [This is most certainly a duplicate] `sleep` is an external command, and **bash will not run any traps while waiting for an external command to finish.** They're only run afterwards. But the SIGTSTP is sent both to your script and to the `sleep` process, and does not cause `sleep` to terminate (like `SIGINT` does) but to *stop*. Once stopped, `^C`/`SIGINT` will also have no effect on either your script or `sleep` until the `sleep` is restarted with e.g. `pkill -CONT sleep`.

Comment: @user414777 Apart from the basic explanation, is there any source you can suggest for the concept of signal? Unfortunatly no basic sources explain such situations. There are many questions in my mind regarding the issue of signal.

Comment: If you use a builtin command (e.g. read -- `bash -c 'trap "echo TSTP" TSTP; read q'`) you will see that the trap works as expected *for your script*.

Comment: No idea, but the fact that the traps are only run afterwards is also described in the [posix standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_11): "When a signal for which a trap has been set is received while the shell is waiting for the completion of a utility executing a foreground command, the trap associated with that signal shall not be executed until after the foreground command has completed."

Comment: **1.** They both *do* work on your `sleep` command -- ^C => INT *terminates* it and ^Z => TSTP *stops* it  **2.** read it again completion of a "utility executing a foreground command" -- that's exactly what `sleep` is in the example.

Comment: @user414777 One more question; Why is this situation valid on bash script not valid on terminal? For example, define the following `trap "echo Ctrl + Z detected !" SIGTSTP` When I enter the `sleep 5; ls ; sleep 5` command, I can pause each command with TSTP. But when I put the same statement in the script file, I don't meet the same situations.

Comment: Scripts don't do job control (unless you use `set -m`). When you run a script, a Control-Z will stop your script **and** all the processes run from inside it (unless they ignore SIGTSTP).

Comment: @user414777 I grateful for enlighten me :)